# .htaccess to WWW And/Or HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

On my site I want to do these redirects:

- `http[s]://example.com` => `https://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com` => `No Redirect`
- `http://sub.example.com` => `https://sub.example.com`
- `http[s]://www.sub.example.com` => `https://sub.example.com`

I've tried many methods but all of them have redirected `http://sub.example.com` to `https://www.sub.example.com`. Which then leads to a *"DNS Not Found"* Or it will redirect to suddenlink search.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your existing directives that are failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> all of them have redirected
>   `http://sub.example.com` To `https://www.sub.example.com`

That would seem to suggest that you have a rule that simply checks for the absence of `www` (which is correct for the first rule, but would conflict with the second) and then prefixes this to the requested *host*.

I assume you also want to redirect `http://example.com/<something>` to `https://www.example.com/<something>` etc?

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This basically states... for all requests that are HTTP (ie. not HTTPS) OR are for `example.com` AND is not for `sub.example.com` (or `www.sub.example.com`) then redirect to `https://www.example.com/...`.

Then add a similar rule block for the subdomain canonicalisation:

```
# sub.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you've cleared the browser cache before testing, since your earlier (erroneous) 301 redirects will have been cached. (It can often be easier to test with 302s for this reason.)

> **UPDATE:** can I do a wildcard on the subdomain?

A subdomain of 1 or more characters...

```
# www.example.com (wildcard subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?[a-z0-9-]+\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# <any-subdomain>.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.[a-z0-9-]+\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The additional `RewriteCond` directive for the subdomain block is required in order to capture the subdomain so we can use this in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (`%1` backreference). The `(?:www\.)?` part of the *CondPattern* is a non-capturing group that makes the `www` sub-subdomain optional, since we need to be able to redirect `sub.example.com` (HTTP) or `www.sub.example.com` (HTTP or HTTPS).

The `%1` backreference in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* matches the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*.

Comment: can I do a wildcard on the subdomain? And my old .htaccess, I deleted it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a "wildcard" subdomain version.

Comment: its taking the [www.]example.com to https, but the subdomain stays at http, i want to make the subdomain go to https aswell, and on the www.*.example.com i just want to remove the www from it [www.*.example.com to *.example.com]

Comment: sorry i ask so much i have looked around for these things and i cant find them.

Comment: I've updated the directives slightly and removed some unnecessary `NC` flags and updated the regex for the subdomain to include digits (the hyphen was also omitted from the main domain's subdomain check). However, this may not change your results. Can you confirm that the subdomain points to the same area of the file system? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories - particularly any that might relate to these subdomain(s)? As always, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing.